# Android studio warning: " this firebase json does not belong to this project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, sha1

When I try to load firebase Json file into my android project, I got this warning: Android studio warning: " this firebase json does not belong to this project". I thought I might have a problem with project, I created new clear project to test it but all the time same warning.
PS. I did it successfully on my previous projects. I got this error around 1 week. And I realized that my android studio gives me the same SHA1 code for any project that I created.
Appreciate for any help!

Comment: the json that you download from firebase and put into your project (assuming you did).... the package name has to match the package name of the app

Comment: Yes, I know that and copied exactly the same name into firebase. Also tested with other project with new firebases. Still not working.. But thank for your answer.

Comment: email firebase. they are quick.